# Как защититься от взлома покупок?

Tags: java, android, android-billing

У меня пока нет аккаунта разработчика, но я уже думаю про защиту покупок в приложении, так как сам пользовался `Lucky patcher` и подобным.

Я искал ответы, но они очень старые, описанное там помечено как устарелое.

Проблема: подделка покупок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё решается просто (в случае Lucky patcher) - вам надо проверять что покупка не фейковая, отправляя токен покупки гуглу для проверки со своего сервера. Т.е. алгоритм такой:

1. Юзер что-то покупает.
2. Приложение получает токен.
3. Шлёт токен на сервер
4. Сервер токен шлёт гуглу.
5. Гугл отвечает ОК/не ОК
6. Сервер перенаправляет эту информацию приложению.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как я могу связяться с сервером гугла?  У меня есть сервер, к которому подключается приложение.

Comment: @HdhisHuxidj, вот дока: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get